# Loop failure, values are not cleared when element = maximum a bug is displayed

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, matrix

I am iterating over the matrix object. Which I create inside the loop, then I modify its values through the increment. When the increment reaches its maximum (51), I have to go back to the outer loop and create a new object one more element. Example: {0: 0, 1: 0}. Now I iterate over the last element in the object, if it = maximum, I go to the next one, from "1" to "0", and increment "0", and "1" = 0. Then I have to iterate over "1".

**But the values are not cleared when element = maximum a bug is displayed.**
[image]

```js
const letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

function check(maxLength) {

  for (let matrixLength = 0; matrixLength < maxLength; matrixLength++) {
    let a = matrix(matrixLength);
    let Indx;
    while (Indx!==null) {
      Indx = getIndex(a,letters.length);
      console.log(increment(a,Indx,Indx));
    }
    
  }
}

function matrix(length) {
  let matrix = {};

  for (let i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
    matrix[i] = 0;
  }

  return matrix;
}


function getIndex(matrix, arrLength) {
  
  for (let i = Object.values(matrix).length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (matrix[i]!==arrLength - 1) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  console.log('null');
  return null;
}

function increment(matrix, index, prevIndex = null) {
  matrix[index]++;

  if (prevIndex === null || index === prevIndex) {
    return matrix;
  }

  for (let i = index + 1; i < Object.values(matrix).length; i++) {
    matrix[i] = 0;
  }

  return matrix;
}
 check(3);
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you should check if Indx is null before increasing:
**if(Indx!==null) console.log(increment(a,Indx,Indx))**
But I don't see any outer loop here, I don't get that.

Comment: @Nat I need my object to be correctly iterated, as I understand it, this does not work: for (let i = index + 1; i <Object.values (matrix) .length; i ++) {
     matrix [i] = 0;}
and also display Null:NaN this`s don`t correct

Comment: Null:NaN is shown because index is equal to null when matrix[index]++ inside increment function

Comment: You should avoid calling the increment function if index is null or add **if (index === null) index = 0;** in first line of increment function (or, of course, any other logic you want to happen when the limit is achieved)

Comment: `i <= length` should be `i < length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether `Indx` is null after calling `getIndex`, not before the next iteration.

```js
const letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

function check(maxLength) {
  for (let matrixLength = 0; matrixLength < maxLength; matrixLength++) {
    let a = matrix(matrixLength);
    while (true) {
      let Indx = getIndex(a, letters.length);
      if (Indx == null) {
        break;
      }
      console.log(increment(a, Indx, Indx));
    }
  }
}

function matrix(length) {
  let matrix = {};
  for (let i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
    matrix[i] = 0;
  }
  return matrix;
}


function getIndex(matrix, arrLength) {
  for (let i = Object.values(matrix).length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (matrix[i] !== arrLength - 1) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  console.log('null');
  return null;
}

function increment(matrix, index, prevIndex = null) {
  matrix[index]++;
  if (prevIndex === null || index === prevIndex) {
    return matrix;
  }

  for (let i = index + 1; i < Object.values(matrix).length; i++) {
    matrix[i] = 0;
  }

  return matrix;
}

check(3);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how can I make it so that when my current matrix [i] reaches the maximum then the iteration of the next matrix [i] starts, for example, instead of "1": 51, it increases "0": 0 by 1 and becomes "0": 1, then it returns by zoomed to 0 "1" and began to iterate it again up to the maximum according to the same logic.

Comment: I don't really understand what your code is trying to do. But maybe use modulus? `matrix[index] = (matrix[index] + 1) % 52;` so the increment wraps around.

Comment: I've already done everything, thanks for the help, I had to rewrite a lot.